# Light box dynamic content are not working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a project and i'm using light box on my portfolio page.when portfolio page opens first time light box works fine
But when i click any of category that is on right side it does not work and when i click it just show me the image.
Basically i am displaying images dynamically.Even i have given the same relation on both page. Kindly help me out about this problem.thanks

sorry brother i'm new to stackoverflow. here is my code for main portfolio page.

```
enter code here
<td width="210"><a href="padmin/files/images/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" class="zoom" rel="lightbox" target="_new" title="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>" rev="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>" style=" border: 2px solid #CCCCCC; height: 182px;width: 294px; display:block;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; padding:4px;"><img src="padmin/files/images/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" class="pimage" /></a>
                </td>
```

and this is a code for categories that I'm using on left side

```
enter code here

<td width="210"><a href="padmin/files/images/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" class="zoom" rel="lightbox" target="_new" title="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>" rev="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>" style=" border: 2px solid #CCCCCC; height: 182px;width: 294px; display:block;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; padding:4px;"><img src="padmin/files/images/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" class="pimage" /></a>
                   </td>
```

both are same but still problem.

Comment: Put it on jsfiddle or somewhere where we can see the problem

Comment: @Sinetheta that too 3 times ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is something you can try because you have posted any sort of code so its all based on assumptions, use `.on()` to bind the click handler to the dynamic content

```
$('a[rel=lightbox]').on('click', function(e){ ... });
```

Comment: 3nigma I'm new to Php kindly elaborat as i have given the code now thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @RizwanTaj the above code attaches a click handler to all the anchor tags that has the `rel` attribute `=lightbox` the `on` function which is added in the jquery version 1.7 takes care of the dynamically added elements to the page if you are using an older version of the jquery it is adviced to update it or use `delegate`

Comment: after alot of hit and trial i changed the slider as getting some idea from 3nigma comment and it's working fine..thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
     <div id="inline" >
                   <img src="padmin/files/images/<?php echo $row['image']">
            </div>

     <td>
    <a href="#inline" class="zoom" title="title." data-description="" >
           <img src="padmin/files/images/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" class="pimage" />

  </a>
</td>
```